# Read lines from a file then search a different file using those values

Tags: bash, csv, grep, cat

I have a file with a list of names in it (`names.txt`) and I have a file with thousands of lines of tab seperated values (`CallLog.tsv`).  I need to `grep` each name in `names.txt` using the `CallLog.tsv` file and then save that as a new file.

Right now I am doing the names individually:

```
grep "John" CallLog.tsv > JohnCallLogs
```

Then I am taking all the names and `cat`'ing them to another file:

```
cat "John" "Mike" "Dave > FilteredCallLogs
```

I want to write a script to make this more efficient.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name; do
  grep "$name" CallLog.tsv
done <names.txt >FilteredCallLogs.tsv
```

`<names.txt` feeds `names.txt` into the loop where `while read name` reads it line-by-line into the loop variable `$name`. `>FilteredCallLogs.tsv` redirects the output from the loop into the file `FilteredCallLogs.tsv`.

Comment: Can you explain to me the last line?

Comment: It seems like it works!  I have never seen the input at the end like that: <names.txt  Very cool.  Thanks.

Comment: For anyone interested, I turned this into a gist. https://gist.github.com/uabassguy/f65c6310b68bfefcb626d4d917767f92

Comment: I have seen *way* too many gists disappear without a trace to consider that service anywhere near useful.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of calling `grep` multiple times (once per name), use the `-f` option to find all matches in one call:

```
grep -f names.txt CallLog.tsv > FilteredCallLogs.tsv
```

If you need the lines grouped by name, you can sort the result on the proper field:

```
# E.g., if the names are in column 2
grep -f names.txt CallLog.tsv | sort -k2,2 > FilteredCallLogs.tsv
```

Comment: I ran the first one and for some reason all of the names were out of order.  I will try out the second one with the sorting.  Thank you.